# Getting unnecessary results while searching through elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, liferay, liferay-7

I have integrated liferay dxp with elastic search. I am searching for the web contents containing "hello" as content. I have only one artice which is having "hello" as its content. But I am getting 28 results through the search query. My query is as follows:-

```
{
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "match": {
          "entryClassName": {
            "query": "com.liferay.journal.model.JournalArticle",
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "match": {
          "status": {
            "query": "0",
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "match": {
          "content": {
            "query": "Hello",
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The url request is **http://localhost:9200/liferay-20116/LiferayDocumentType**
In this search, I am getting 28 results in which only one result is corrrect. I don't know why the filter for journal article is not working as desired. Please help..thanx in advance..

Comment: Can you show how you are sending your query?

Comment: I am sending the query using gui using elasticsearch head plugin by accessing it through http://localhost:9200/_plugin/head.

Comment: Then you're probably using the GET method and you should use POST instead if you want it to send the query.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was using GET instead of POST. Now I rectified my mistake and am getting desired results. Thanks a lot.. :)

Comment: Cool, that's a classic trap.